# Why can't I send tweet from Python?

Tags: python, api, twitter

```
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=' ',
                       consumer_secret=' ',
                        access_token_key=' ',
                        access_token_secret=' ')

friends=api.PostUpdate("First Tweet from PYTHON APP ")
```

I have done everything as said at http://abhi74k.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/tweeting-from-python/ but when I full inside it and press enter, nothing happens. Can you help me about that?

Ok it is because of that I couldn't download python-twitter API correctly. It gives me this error when I try to follow those steps:

```
figen@figen-Satellite-A350:~/Downloads/python-twitter-0.8.2$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/twitter.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter.py: Permission denied
```

http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

Ok I installed `setup.py` but now it gives this error:

```
figen@figen-Satellite-A350:~/Downloads/python-twitter-0.8.2$ python twitter_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_test.py", line 29, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "/home/figen/Downloads/python-twitter-0.8.2/twitter.py", line 65, in <module>
    import oauth2 as oauth
ImportError: No module named oauth2
```

Now it says twitter module doesn't have the module. How to get it?

```
  api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='removed',
                       consumer_secret='removed',
                        access_token_key='removed',
                        access_token_secret='removed')

  friends=api.PostUpdate("If you see this,I managed to send my first tweet from Python    Shell. Yay! =)")
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
  api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='removed for security=)',
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

Comment: OK this might be a stupid question, but this isn't the actual code you are trying to run? Did you have the keys filled in when you were trying it?

Comment: Yes, i filled them. I updated question. Can you look at it again,please?

Comment: Try `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: Thx Peter, it worked but now it gives another error. Could you look at  updated question again?

Comment: @FigenGungor: "No module named oauth2" is a straightforward error message: you need the oauth2 module installed.

Comment: @FigenGungor, `sudo apt-get install python-oauth2`

Comment: Thank you, i sudownloaded them. But now i get this new updated error.

Comment: Please could you look at it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things causing your problem.

1) The permission denied error (error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter.py: Permission denied) is because you do not have administrator privileges. Try `sudo python setup.py install`

2) You need to install the missing dependencies (i.e. oauth2) you can get oauth2 from here http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2 make sure you have the other dependencies needed which are SimpleJson and HTTPLib2. You can find more details on this information on the [python-twitter-api site](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter).

Hope this solves it!

Answer (score -1):

You need to install twitter which include Api . http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/downloads/detail?name=python-twitter-0.8.2.tar.gz this version contain Api .

Comment: This is a non-answer. The OP is already using the suggested package version. Also the problem had already been solved by a previous answer.